# How to get scrapy to continue iterating through websites even with errors?

Tags: python, scrapy

So I'm relatively new to scrapy and am trying to get a crawler that pulls hyper links for businesses on a listing page. Here is the code:

```
class EmailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "emailcrawler"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Computer+Software+%26+Services&geo_location_terms=Florence%2C+KY'
        # 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Computers+%26+Computer+Equipment-Service+%26+fix&geo_location_terms=FL'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        information = response.xpath('//*[@class="info"]')
        for info in information:
            website = info.xpath('.//*[@class="links"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            if website != "None":
                request = Request(url = website, callback=self.parse_email, errback = self.handle_error,
                                  meta={'dont_retry': True, 'dont_redirect':True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]})
                request.meta['data'] = {
                    'Website': website
                }

                # yield response.follow(url = website, callback = self.parse_email)
                yield request
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="next ajax-page"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url, errback = self.handle_error, meta={'dont_retry': True, 'dont_redirect':True})

    def parse_email(self, response):
        data = response.meta.get('data')
        # try:
        #     emails = set(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.com", response.text, re.I))
        # except AttributeError:
        #     return
        # data['email'] = emails
        selector = Selector(response)
        for found_address in selector.re('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.com'):
            # item = EmailAddressItem()
            data['email_address'] = found_address
            # item['url'] = response.url
            yield data

    def handle_error(self, failure):
        self.log("Request failed: %s" % failure.request)
```

Before I attempted to get scrapy to follow each link, I had it just return the list of websites that it pulled which worked perfectly. It was able to request the next page after iterating through the urls on the page and then yield the results. What I am trying to do now is to get it to go to each website that it pulls, extract an email element on that website if it is found and then return back to the loop and then try another website. The problem is that when the crawler gets a response error the crawl just stops. It also seems like even if the Request was successful, that the crawler is not going to be able to return to the original iteration through the yellowpages url. It gets stuck in one of the websites that it follows and then the for loop dies. How can I get the crawler to stay its course and keep attempting to pull from the websites it scrapes while also staying within the process of iterating through each page of the listing website. To put it simply, I need to be able to go through every single page on the initial listing page no matter what request error comes about, but have the crawler pop in and out of the websites it finds and attempt to scrape data on those sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class EmailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "followwebsite"
    start_urls = [
        # 'https://www.manta.com/mb_35_D000B000_000/offices_and_clinics_of_medical_doctors',
         # 'https://www.chess.com/home'
         # 'https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/static'
        'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Computer+Software+%26+Services&geo_location_terms=Florence%2C+KY'
        'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Computers+%26+Computer+Equipment-Service+%26+fix&geo_location_terms=FL'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        website = response.xpath('//*[@class="links"]/a/@href')
        yield from response.follow_all(website, self.parse_email)

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="next ajax-page"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url, errback = self.handle_error)

    def parse_email(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        for found_address in selector.re('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.com'):
            item = EmailAddressItem()
            item['email_address'] = found_address
            # item['url'] = response.url
            yield item

    def handle_error(self, failure):
        self.log("Request failed: %s" % failure.request)
```

Figured it out no thanks to you bums